# Link a file throught docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to link a file throught a docker service.
I have 1 service (traefik) looking for some file in a directory.
I have another service: "whoami" with a conf file next to it.
I want to link the conf file in a specific shared volume throught docker, so i did that:

```yaml
  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    networks:
      - traefik
    volumes:
      - "./whoami.yml:/etc/traefik/conf/whoami.yml"
      - "./conf:/etc/traefik/conf"
```

The file appear in ./conf but is empty.

Someone have an idea on how to do this ?
I do not want to copy/paste some file each time I start/stop a service.

Comment: I tried locally and I don't have this kind of issue. Unless you're copying the wrong file, it should be working. On what OS are you running this thing?

Comment: I am on arch linux.
And i still confirm ./conf/whoami.yml is empty even when ./whoami.yml is full

Comment: oh, wait. maybe I misunderstood. the problem is that the file in the /etc/traefik/conf is empty. correct?

Comment: I have to test with another image (this one is done with 'scratch' so i cannot check the inside of the service). The file in ./conf (link throught /etc/traefik/conf in the service) is empty, that's the issue

Comment: but beside the file ./conf, is the file in /etc/traefik/conf properly filled? I ask this because with your setup, even if you have a ./conf/whoami.yml, it'll be "overwritten" in the container by ./whoami.yml. This will not be reflected in the host obviously.

Comment: .conf is a directory empty at start and with the whoami.yml empty ay yhe end. Why it will not be reflected ?

Comment: because if you have another whoami.yml in ./conf it'd be rewritten and any setup based on that file would not make sense.

Comment: no no ./conf is empty at start

Comment: this would be an edge case that would create tons of problems. What I don't understand is: why don't you simply use the same file?

Comment: Because it's for traefik who listen a folder. When i want too add a service i just want to automaticly link the conf file of the service and when i stopn it would be great that the file is unlink. Like that i do not have to copy paste the file each time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222352/discussion-between-artentica-and-stefano).